# What does it mean that a qubit is a triple $(H,X,Z)$ with $H$ Hilbert space and $X,Z$ Pauli operators?

Tags: quantum-state, pauli-gates

In this paper, [http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~vidick/teaching/fsmp/fsmp.pdf](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Evidick/teaching/fsmp/fsmp.pdf), it gives the definition of a qubit as follows:

A qubit is a triple $(H, X, Z)$ consisting of a separable Hilbert space H and
a pair of Hermitian operators $X, Z$ acting on a H such that $X^2 = Z^2 = Id$ and ${X, Z} = XZ + ZX = 0$.

What does this mean and why does this work? Can I choose any two pauli observables?

Comment: Section 1.2.2 of that paper, where the definition you mention is introduced, later explains the intuition and formality behind the definition. Is there any particular part of that explanation that you have trouble with?

Comment: And to what two observables do you refer? X and Z are chosen because they make up the Hadamard and computational basis, respectively. This is also mentioned in the explanation of the definition in the same paper.

Comment: That sounds like a very mathematical definition of a qubit ...

Comment: Hi @epelaaez, thank you! It seems to me that this is key: Informally, we will distinguish a quantum degree of freedom from a classical one by requiring that the quantum degree of freedom can be measured (observed) in two mutually incompatible ways.

Comment: Essentially, we are requiring that the two operators we chose are as incompatible as possible. 

However, what I don't understand is why this provides us with two degrees of freedom. Is it because one can't be constructed from the other. The relation between the classical and quantum definition seems a bit imprecise to me.

Comment: I believe that this refers to the fact that classical bits can only be measured on one basis: the computational basis in which their result will be 0 or 1. However, qubits give us the possibility of measuring them in two different bases. I guess we choose the X and Z operators because the eigenvalues of X are a "balanced" (equal amplitude) linear combination of the eigenvalues of Z.

Comment: Right so we can choose any two pauli operators though right?

Comment: As explained there, this is isomorphic to the usual notion of qubit coupled to any extra external enviornment that is not touched by the operators. There is always an environment around, and this definition abstracts the notion of them being completely separate.

Comment: @snickers_stickers I think in principle yes, we can choose any two pauli operators. But choosing Z gives us the computational basis that helps us interpret our results. And I guess we choose X over Y since it doesn't introduce complex numbers, so it is more convinient. I'm not sure about this last part though.

Comment: Cool thank you -- I think I am happy with what I understand now.

Comment: @snickers_stickers awesome, I’m happy to help